# Return everything before a certain character

Tags: php, string, explode

i'm trying to return everything from my title before the dash here is my code

```
$mystring = "Nymphomaniac: Volume 1 – Nimfomana Vol. I (2013) – filme online"; 
$mystring = str_replace(' ', '+', $mystring);
$mystring = str_replace('-', '(/', $mystring);
$parts1 = explode("(", $mystring); 
//break the string up around the "(" character in $mystring 

$mystrings = $parts1[0]; 
echo $mystrings;
```

the output is this

```
Output:

Nymphomaniac:+Volume+1+–+Nimfomana+Vol.+I+
```

what i want to get is this

```
Output:

Nymphomaniac:+Volume+1
```

i think that the problem is that there are 2 dashes i've tried everything but didn't work, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php

    $mystring = "Nymphomaniac: Volume 1 – Nimfomana Vol. I (2013) – filme online"; 
    $array = explode("–", $mystring);
    $string = str_replace(" ", "+", trim($array[0]));

    echo $string; //Prints Nymphomaniac:+Volume+1

?>
```

[Here's the demo](https://eval.in/152946)

Comment: why does work with this title "Nymphomaniac: Volume 1 – Nimfomana Vol. I (2013) – filme online" and with this title doesn't "Banlieue 13 - Ultimatum - 2009 - Film Online"

Comment: @user3649605 "–" (dash) and "-" (hyphen) are two different characters. The text in your code uses dash and the one your posting uses hyphen. Change the dash in my answer to hyphen and it will work.